# How to load characters from a text file (maze) into a data structure to operate on later?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, text, 2d

I have a text file which contains the details of a maze. First i'd like to take the text file and load it into some sort of data structure. I first thought i'd use a 2d array as it represents a 2d maze pretty well however i'm leaning more towards a vector due to the extra funtionality provided. The reason I want to load it into a data structure is so I can then operate on it later using some sort of pathfinding algorithm to solve the maze. Here is an example of a maze:

```html
xxxxxxx
xA...Bx
xxxxxxx
```

However I am finding this challenge quite difficult when it comes to loading in the characters into a data structure properly. I'm not necessarily looking for a black and white answer just some pointers in the right direction so I can learn and complete the challenge on my own. I have been attempting this for the past few days and haven't made much progress (feeling like an idiot), help is much appreciated.

Comment: use a `std::vector<std::string>` it perfectly represents contents of a file and as a maze it isnt too bad either

Comment: I was thinking a `std::vector<std::char>` but does it make much difference from storing it as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file line by line:

```cpp
for (std::string line, std::getline(file_stream, line);)
{
  vector.push_back(line);
}
```

And if you want to iterate over every character, you can use `for-range-loop` (C++11):

```cpp
for (const auto& line : vector)
{
  for (const auto one_char : line)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `file_stream` in this case?

Comment: It could be `std::ifstream`.

Comment: Okay so currently I have successfully got the file reading line by line using `while (std::getline(infile, line))` and `maze.push_back(line);`  However how can I modify this method to read character by character, so each element of the vector consists of one character so I can operate on them individually later?

Comment: answer is edited.

Comment: Okay i'm on the right lines now, just to clarify before I mark the answer. So since it iterates through each line by char I could place an if statement in the second nested for loop which checks for a specific char. For example I could check if 'A' has been found in that line?

Comment: First i suggest to learn programming with C++: learncpp.com then try to programming with it.

Comment: I've managed to use this implementation to create and store a vector of characters which was the topic in question so I will mark the question as answered. Thanks for the help Anthony, much appreciated.